# Integrating with Marketing cloud : Create a data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to create data extension from PHP application into Salesforce Marketing Cloud and I am following [**this documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm). However when the page actually renders, I am getting error "Page isnt't working" After I looked into code found that there is space in below line between `Marketing` and `CloudSoapClient`:

`$client = new Marketing CloudSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));`

Is this normal? Because if I remove that line or comment that line, everything again seems working normal means no errors but functionality still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me -- a poorly executed search and replace in the documentation.

I'm guessing it doesn't match the PHP SDK method you're using either.

I've found that the SOAP envelopes are the best examples on how to structure SFMC API calls.  There's are a few of those farther down on the page you referenced.

I'd use the `[+] Feedback` button at the bottom of the page and let them know it's not correct.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Will look into the SOAP and give it a try. Thanks for pointing me there.